# on RegionPlot3D and ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

First I have

```
ContourPlot3D[{
  (1 - p1) (1 - p2)^3 == p1 p2^3, 
  p1 p2^6 (c p1 + (1 - c) p2)^3 ((1 - c) p1 + c p2)^2 
    == (1 - p1) (1 -p2)^6 (1 - c p1 - (1 - c) p2)^3 (1 - (1 - c) p1 - c p2)^2
 }, {p1, 0.2, 0}, {p2, 1, 0.5}, {c, 0, 1}, 
Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]), 
Mesh -> None, 
BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1},
ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20}]
```

which will show me (please don't mind the labels)

[image]

I want *Mathematica* to plot the region between the yellow plane and the transparent red plane, so I use `RegionPlot3D` with the same set of equations.

```
RegionPlot3D[(1 - p1) (1 - p2)^3 > p1 p2^3 && 
  p1 p2^6 (c p1 + (1 - c) p2)^3 (c p2 + (1 - c) p1)^2 
   > (1 - p1) (1 - p2)^6 (1 - (c p1 + (1 - c) p2))^3 (1 - (c p2 + (1 - c) p1))^2, 
{p1, 0, 0.2}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, 
Mesh -> None, FaceGrids -> All, ViewPoint -> Front,PlotPoints->100]
```

which will give me the following:

[image]

One will expect `RegionPlot3D` will give a single connected bulk but instead there are several rod-like artifacts. How to get a nice region plot with that set of equations? (Increasing plotpoints to 200 might work, but it takes so long...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can just plot the boundary surface of the region piece by piece, and then combine them together to shape the region:

```
funcSet = {
   (1 - p1) (1 - p2)^3 - p1 p2^3,
   -(1 - p1) (1 - p2)^6 (1 - c p1 - (1 - c) p2)^3 (1 - (1 - c) p1 - 
       c p2)^2 + p1 p2^6 (c p1 + (1 - c) p2)^3 ((1 - c) p1 + c p2)^2
   };

Clear[regionBoundaryPlot]
regionBoundaryPlot[f1_, f2_, opts___] := With[
  {f2$temp = f2 /. {p1 -> p1$, p2 -> p2$, c -> c$}},
  ContourPlot3D[f1 == 0,
   {p1, 0, 0.2}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, {c, 0, 1},
   opts,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{p1, p2, c}, f2$temp > 0]
   ]]

Show[{
  regionBoundaryPlot[funcSet[[1]], funcSet[[2]],
   Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Blue,
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{p1, p2, c}, Evaluate[funcSet[[2]]]],
   PlotPoints -> 40],
  regionBoundaryPlot[funcSet[[2]], funcSet[[1]],
   Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Gray,
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{p1, p2, c}, Evaluate[funcSet[[1]]]],
   PlotPoints -> 40]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{0, .05}, All, All}, BoxRatios -> {.5, 1, .5}]
```

[image: region plot]

Comment: Nice idea! Is there anything special with the variables (in your `regionBoundaryPlot` function) whose names contain "$"?

Comment: @wdg Thanks for accepting. It's because `With` renamed the variables inside it. Check this: `With[{y = x}, Function[x, y]]`. Note it may not be the best way to *inject* code into `Function`, please do search relevant posts on this site.